# vue v-model message dynamic not printing

Tags: vuejs2

I want to get display dynamic value in the text box. I am passing the value through 'message' and I want to display 'Welcome to My project' in text box default and when I change the text in the text box it dynamically changes this "

My input value: {{ message }}.

message place.

https://prnt.sc/p4quj7

```
<div id="main"> 
<input type="text" id="input" v-model="message"> 
<p>My input value: {{ message }}.</p> 
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script> 
let data={message: 'Welcome to my project'}; 
new Veu({ 
el:'#main', 
data : data})
</script>
```

Error Message --- My input value: {{ message }}.

Comment: is it because of typo - new Veu instead of new Vue

Comment: Fix the typo issue and it should work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/7qhw5ezc/

Comment: Thanks, @AjinderSingh Now it's working time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have "dynamic" data otherwise known as "reactive" you need to set it up within the the vue data property(preferably as a **function** even though here would work as a property), then it will automatically update (with certain caveats) on change in your template.There isn't really a reason to declare outside the data property like you did.
like so:

```
data(){
 return {
   message: 'welcome to my project'
   }
```

In addition you need to correct the typo that has been pointed out.